# Django using pre_save to assign username to user if username was empty due to an error

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to use `pre_save` signal to assign random username to any user if due to an error their username was empty (Social login or edit profile error). Currently, I have:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Profile)
def set_username(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.username:
        rand = random.getrandbits(64)
        username = "user" + str(rand)
        while Profile.objects.filter(username=username):
            rand = random.getrandbits(64)
            username = "user" + str(rand)
        instance.username = username
```

Now I was wondering to be safer, how can I generally filter out profiles in my `ProfileManager`?
Can I change the `get_queryset()` method? Since I read that isn't safe to do so. Or is my `pre_save` signal enough to make sure users will always have a username no matter what?

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively overwrite the `username` field by inheriting the `AbstractBaseUser` model. Then auto generate the username as a default value in the **models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser 
import random

def get_auto_username():
    rand = random.getrandbits(64)
    username = "user" + str(rand)
    return username

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
   username = models.CharField(default=get_auto_username)
   [...]
```

Here whenever a use is create a default is always created if empty.

*Note: You made need to include a quick validation on the very off chance the generated username is already created*

Comment: Will this work if my User model is `AbstractUser` as well?

Comment: @ashes999 I believe so yes.